# Getting scrollTo to work inside iframe on iOS

Tags: jquery, ios, iframe, scrollto, iframe-resizer

I have a page on mysite.com that is using an iframe to pull in content from subdomain.mysite.com. I am using the `iframe-resizer` script (https://github.com/davidjbradshaw/iframe-resizer) to ensure that the height of the `iframe` always matches the height of its content. Works like a charm cross-browser/OS.

Within the `iframe` is a long form with client-side validation. If the user tries to submit the form and it doesn't fully validate, I use scrollTo (on the form page that's within the iframe) to scroll the page to the top of the form where they are presented with a detailed error message. This all works great across desktop browsers (Mac and Windows) and on all Android devices -- w/r/t scrollTo scrolling to the top of the form within the `iframe`.

However, on iOS, it does not work -- the scrolling to the top of the form that is inside the iframe does not happen. I've read about how, since 2011, on iOS you need to turn on the ability for the iframe to be scrolled -- I'm not sure if doing this would solve my issue. I read about adding `style="overflow:auto; -webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch;"` to the div that surrounds the `iframe`, and tried this, but it didn't have any impact.

I can't tell yet if I haven't found the right solution to get this working in iOS, or if there's no way for scrollTo to work inside of an iframe when on iOS. Thoughts?

Comment: Having the exact same issue. If anyone knows of an answer please let me know

Comment: can you share the code you have used to scroll inside the iframe?

Comment: please leave a link to test the problem in live demo.
One more question and advice at the same time: try appending scrollTo using .on()
How do you append scrollTo?

Answer (score 0):

I see that you are using **iFrame-Resizer**. This provides its own version of `scrollTo()` in the iframe that should overcome this issue, as it passes the request to the parent page.

```
if ('parentIFrame' in window) {
  parentIFrame.scrollTo(0,0)
} else {
  window.scrollTo(0,0)
}
```

https://github.com/davidjbradshaw/iframe-resizer/blob/master/docs/iframed_page/methods.md#scrolltoxy